# ASP.NET Razor MVC Core WebApplication - problem with Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

following to [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-session-in-asp-net-core/)

When im trying to build app maked like this, i have problem in HomeController.cs :

> Error CS1061: 'ISession' does not contain a definition for 'SetString'
>   and no extension method 'SetString' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ISession' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?) (CS1061) (sessionTest)
>
> Error CS1061: 'ISession' does not contain a definition for 'GetString' 
>   and no extension method 'GetString' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ISession' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?) (CS1061) (sessionTest)

It looks like i can't set session values as string, int etc. I can only do it with `Set` and it suggest me to use

> String and byte[]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Nuget package` `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` to your project.

This will give you the extension methods for Session, such as `SetString` `GetString`, etc.

Remember to add:

> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

Comment: Just add to project or use ? Because when im using its not working.

Comment: @Kamil You need to go under `Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution` in `Visual Studio` then search the web for the package I listed in my answer. It will then ask if you want to install this package to your project, which you should choose yes.

Comment: i have a mac .. cant find NPM in Tools

Comment: @Kamil Do you have Visual Studio?

Comment: My packages now:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App;